# Why is any config file for ripgrep excluded using the --no-config flag in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ripgrep

In

**src\vs\workbench\services\search\node\ripgrepFileSearch.ts:74**

there is a command line flag for ripgrep to exclude any defined config files for ripgrep

**args.push('--no-config');**

Why is that there? What is the reasoning behind not respecting any settings a user might have for using ripgrep?

FYI: I'm asking this question because I have a lot of excluded folders (managed by my own extension) in my vscode **files.exclude** setting, which causes the ripgrep command to fail because of the lenght of the command for all the added ignored folders. I want to add these excluded files to a ripgrep configuration file, but due to the mentioned code that configuration is ignored.

Comment: I think this question would be better asked on [the vscode issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I checked their repo and they pointed me here though. But, let's do it there too ;-) I'll rephrase it as a feature request ....

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149727